# Construction of a set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $B,Y$ two closed sets from a Banach space $X$, such that $Y\not\subset [X\setminus \rm int(B)]$, i have to find a set $D\neq\emptyset$ such that :

$D$ is closed,

$D\subset B$ and

$\rm int(D)\subset [X\setminus Y]$

how to find it please ?

Comment: no i don't need the emptyset

Comment: What about the closure of $B \setminus Y$?

Comment: $\rm clo(B\setminus Y)=\rm clo(B\cap [X\setminus Y])\subset \rm clo(X\setminus Y)$

Comment: What is X? Is it the Banach space?

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes

Answer (score 1):

The premise is equivalent to $Y \cap \operatorname{int} B$ is not empty.
Let $b$ be any point in $B$.  Take $D = \{b\}$.

Comment: is there a relation between your $\{b\}$ and the fact that $Y\cap int(B)\neq \emptyset $ ? thank you

Comment: int D is empty.  As int B is not empty, B is nit empty.

Comment: where is used the fact that $Y\cap int(B)\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: To assure B is not empty.

Comment: do you think that i can consider $D=B\setminus int(Y)$

Comment: Yes, you can consider it or any other conjecture.   I however, will not consider it.

Comment: but i have a problem to prove $int(D)\subset [X\setminus Y]$ do you have an idea on how i can prove it ? thank you

Comment: Show int D is empty.

Comment: Why ? $int(D)=int(B \cap [X\setminus int(Y)])$ we know that $int(B)\cap int([X\setminus(int(Y))]\subset int(B \cap [X\setminus int(Y)])$  from where i can get that $int(D)$ is empty ?

Comment: int D is empty because D is a singleton.

Comment: $D=B\cap [X\setminus int(Y)]$ is a singleton ?

Comment: D = {b}........

Comment: I understand for your example, i'am asking for my example $D=B\setminus int(Y)$